# Subselect dentro de um campo

Tags: sql

Estou exibindo vários campos através de um SELECT:

`SELECT razaosocial, nomefantasia, cnpj, ie, im, endereco, endereco_numero, endereco_complemento, codCedente FROM cliente WHERE razaosocial LIKE '%carvalho%'`.

Até ai, tudo certo. Mas ali exibo também o codCedente, que vem numerico, tem como eu fazer um SELECT ali dentro do codCedente para buscar a razaosocial dentro de uma tabela chamada CEDENTE? (select razaosocial from cedente where codCedente = 'codCedente') as codCedente.. digamos dessa forma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explicação

Acredito que a forma mais fácil (acredito que mais performática também) de realizar essa consulta seria utilizar o `JOIN` com a tabela **Cedente**.

## Query

```
SELECT 
    c.razaosocial, 
    c.nomefantasia, 
    c.cnpj, 
    c.ie, 
    c.im, 
    c.endereco, 
    c.endereco_numero, 
    c.endereco_complemento, 
    ce.razaosocial
FROM 
    cliente c 
    INNER JOIN cedente ce on ce.codCedente = c.codCedente
WHERE 
    razaosocial LIKE '%carvalho%'
```

Comment: Sim, eu mesmo faria dessa forma. Porém, não é este o objetivo! Preciso selecionar direto no campo, porque eu passo estes parametros via get, de quais campos o sistema deverá compor para exibir.

Comment: if($valor=="faturamento_dados"){ $campos .= ", (SELECT razaosocial FROM cedente WHERE idCedente = codCedente) AS codCedente, email_financeiro, vencimento, forma_de_pagamento, nota, fechamento_de, fechamento_a, guias"; } - Fiz dessa forma.

Comment: Já resolveu seu problema com o sub-select na coluna?

Comment: Sim já resolvi sim